# bayesian structural time series model question

Tags: time-series, bayesian, causality

I am using the R package CausalImpact to make some causal inference.

Does the response variable y need to be independent (has to be daily or weekly data, etc.)? Can I use data that are related (data from a sliding window, for example, each data point contains data for the past 28 days)?

The reason I am asking is because the daily data is very noisy, while data from the sliding window is more smooth.

Comment: Overlapping binning has been used to noise reduce data before see the appendix in this [Wesolowski CA, Conrad GR, Kirchner PT. A direct modeling approach to the early renal vascular transit of 99mTc chelates. Medical Physics. 1987;14:1032-41. doi:10.1118/1.596117.](https://aapm.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1118/1.596117), which shows that the order of convolution of a moving window of data smoothing is irrelevant, as long as its usage is consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the reference Carl!